# 2D clickable surface in Pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm writing a simple GUI interface for a project using **PySide2**.
I'm using the typical MVC design pattern, for the sake of clarity I will just post the code of my GUI (without controller and support methods ecc...)

Here's the code:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QMainWindow)

class myView(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """View initializer."""

        #Creates blank view of a given size
        super().__init__()

        # Set some main window's properties
        self.setWindowTitle('8D.me')
        self.setFixedSize(800, 500) # Block user resize of the window
        self.setIcon()
        self.generalLayout = QHBoxLayout() #Layout generale

        self.button = QPushButton('test3',self)
        self.button.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Preferred,
            QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('test2',self),1)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.button,3)

        # Set the central widget
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self) #creates a QWidget object to play the role of a central widget. Remember that since your GUI class inherits from QMainWindow, you need a central widget. This object will be the parent for the rest of the GUI component.
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)

# Insert methods for creating/adding elements to the default view.
# Mehods....
    def setIcon(self):
        appIcon = QIcon('logo')
        self.setWindowIcon(appIcon)

#Insert here the public methods called by the Controller to update the view...
```

My GUI right no is pretty simple and looks like this:

[image: GUI]

What I would like to do is change the `test 3` button and insert a 2D clickable surface.
More in details, I would like to be able to click anywhere on this surface and get the position of the mouse click.

Basically I would like to create a 2D xy axis and retrieve the coordinates of my mouse click, something like this:
[image: Axis]

And then if I click at position `(1,1)` I wll print something like "You clicked at (1,1) on the axis", pretty simple.

I looked around for examples, tutorials and documentation, but I didn't find any proper tool to create what I wanted.
Is there any class inside the PySide2 package that could help me?

Comment: Technically it's pretty easy: subclass from QWidget and implement its [`mousePressEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent), its [`event`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) argument has the `pos` property, which provides the coordinates in pixels from the top left corner of the widget. The problem is that completely depends on what you're going to do *afterwards*. If the widget will always be as simple, that's ok, but if you're going to develop something more complex, then you should explain what you're planning to do more specifically.

Comment: My final goal is to create a 3D audio simulator. From the point of view of DSP/Model, there's no problem, I already have the code. I just need to retrieve the coordinates on my 2D plane and then pass them to my model, compute some audio filtering ecc... and adjust the audio playback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you took literally that your goal is to get the X-Y plane in your image then a possible solution is to use a QGraphicsView:

```
import math
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QPointF
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPainterPath
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    clicked = Signal(QPointF)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        l = min(rect.width(), rect.height()) / 30

        x_left = QPointF(rect.left(), 0)
        x_right = QPointF(rect.right(), 0)
        painter.drawLine(x_left, x_right)

        right_triangle = QPainterPath()
        right_triangle.lineTo(-0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l, 0.5 * l)
        right_triangle.lineTo(-0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l, -0.5 * l)
        right_triangle.closeSubpath()
        right_triangle.translate(x_right)

        painter.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        painter.drawPath(right_triangle)

        y_top = QPointF(0, rect.top())
        y_bottom = QPointF(0, rect.bottom())
        painter.drawLine(y_top, y_bottom)

        top_triangle = QPainterPath()
        top_triangle.lineTo(.5*l, -0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l)
        top_triangle.lineTo(-.5*l, -0.5 * math.sqrt(3) * l)
        top_triangle.closeSubpath()
        top_triangle.translate(y_bottom)

        painter.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        painter.drawPath(top_triangle)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        sp = event.scenePos()
        self.clicked.emit(sp)
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class MyView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("8D.me")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 500)

        self.btn = QPushButton("test2")

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.view.scale(1, -1)
        self.scene = GraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.scene.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_clicked(self, p):
        print("clicked", p.x(), p.y())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyView()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Is it too much if I ask you to comment the code? So people will understand easily what is written and what it's doing

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio What have you not understood the code? the code is quite readable so I think the comments are unnecessary. Anyone who knows anything about basic Qt should understand it.

Comment: I just don't get how the function drawBackground is called, it doesn't seem to be called anywhere and it's not the constructor of the class. I'm surely missing something

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Do you understand what inheritance is? I recommend you review your OOP concepts and the Qt docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#drawBackground, the drawBackground method is an inherited method that was called by the base class

Comment: Yes, I've worked with Java in the past. I was looking for the initialization of the parent class but i wasn't able to find it in the documentation. So basically QGraphicsScene calls drawBackground in its constructor?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio A class has a behavior, and to give the developer the ability to modify that behavior it implements methods that can be overridden. So somewhere in the code of the base class that method was invoked, it is not the constructor nor does it interest to know where, it is only necessary to know that in that method the background is painted. It seems that you are starting in Qt so please look for tutorials, read the Qt docs, for example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html, etc.